# debug buttons in netbeans are disabled

Tags: java

for some reasons the debug buttons are disabled in debugging mode. Tried to look for similar questions about it online but coudn't find a solution. it's netbeans 8.2. It shows also which plugins are activated in case.

[image: MAIN IDE SCREEN]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The only way i could solve it was by reinstalling netbeans. Since then it works again